# FFmpeg Statistical CallBack Swift

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, ffmpeg

I have added FFmpeg with pods and it loads fine. The execution of command done succuefully and the video output is created. The only problem is am not getting call back updates from ffmpeg even tho I have enabled MobileFFmpegConfig.setStatisticsDelegate(self).

```swift
 class FFmpegStatisticsHandler: NSObject, StatisticsDelegate {
    func statisticsCallback(_ statistics: Statistics!) {
        print("statics")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("statX")
            let timeInMilliseconds = statistics.getTime()
            let progress = (Double(timeInMilliseconds) / self.totalDuration) * 100

            // use the plugin reference to send message back to JS
            let pluginResult = CDVPluginResult(
                status: CDVCommandStatus_OK,
                messageAs: "progress:\(progress)"
            )
            print("progress:\(progress)")
            pluginResult?.setKeepCallbackAs(true)
            self.plugin?.commandDelegate.send(pluginResult, callbackId: self.command?.callbackId)
        }
        
    }
    
    weak var plugin: CDVPlugin?
    var command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand?
    var totalDuration: Double = 0
    var cmd : String

    init(plugin: CDVPlugin, command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand, totalDuration: Double, cmd: String) {
        self.plugin = plugin
        self.command = command
        self.totalDuration = totalDuration
        self.cmd = cmd
        super.init()
        print("createdD")
        self.execute()
    }
    func execute(){
        MobileFFmpegConfig.resetStatistics()
        MobileFFmpegConfig.setStatisticsDelegate(self)
        let rc = MobileFFmpeg.execute(cmd)
        if (rc == RETURN_CODE_SUCCESS) {
            print("Command execution completed successfully.\n")
        } else if (rc == RETURN_CODE_CANCEL) {
            print("Command execution cancelled by user.\n")
        } else {
            print("Command execution failed with rc=\(rc).\n")
        }
        
    }
}
```

Document:
https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg